# uploading a tarball via ansible URI module provides a BAD_TAR_ARCHIVE error from server

Tags: curl, ansible, node-red

### Description

I am referring to [Node-RED's HTTP POST `/nodes` API](https://nodered.org/docs/api/admin/methods/post/nodes/) where it provides a possibility to upload `.tgz` files to the system via the `/nodes` API.

I have certain downloaded NPM packages as as `.tgz` locally on a controller machine and I wish to upload them via a Playbook.

#### `curl` command

According to the Documentation a local tarball can be uploaded to the `/nodes` API via the equivalent `curl` command:

```bash
curl -XPOST http://localhost:1880/nodes \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <USER_TOKEN_HERE>" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \

-F "tarball=@path/node-red-contrib-foo-0.1.0.tgz;type=application/x-compressed-tar;filename=node-red-contrib-foo-0.1.0.tgz"
```

#### Ansible `uri` Module Task

According to Ansible's [`uri` module docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html#examples), the equivalent the above `curl`

```yaml
# previous tasks removed for brewity
# -SNIP

- name: Upload tarballs for Nodes
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: "http://localhost:1880/nodes"
    method: POST
    headers:
      Authorization: "{{ auth_token.json.token_type }} {{ auth_token.json.access_token }}"
    body_format: form-multipart
    body:
      tarball:
        filename: "path/node-red-contrib-foo-0.1.0.tgz"
        mime_type: "application/x-compressed-tar"
```

#### Error Results

Upon executing the playbook the server replies with:

```
#- SNIP

  json:
    code: TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
    message: 'TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format'
  msg: 'Status code was 400 and not [200]: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request'
```

which is the error raised from the server when trying to unpack the `.tgz` send on the API.

Ironically,

The `curl` command above works from the CLI as well as when wrapped around a `command` task in Ansible e.g.

```yaml
- ansible.builtin.command:
        cmd: >
          curl -XPOST http://localhost:1880/nodes -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
           -H "Authorization: {{ auth_token.json.token_type }} {{ auth_token.json.access_token }}" \
           -F "tarball=@path/node-red-contrib-foo-0.1.0.tgz;type=application/x-compressed-tar;filename=node-red-contrib-foo-0.1.0.tgz"
```

### Question

1. Is there some equivalent command in `curl` that I am missing out for the body of `uri` module?

I have played around with multiple combinations of `uri` body parameters but the output is the same for server. Yet the same tarballs seem to be accepted via `command` module.

2. If using the `command` is the only way possible at the moment, how to register a variable for `command` task with `curl` that can help me decide the output based on the HTTP response code? at the moment all the outputs for the task yield `rc: 3` values

Comment: I suggest you use wireshark/tcpdump to check what the ansible is actually sending, I'll guess it's messing up the `filename` (including the path)

Comment: @hardillb I suspect that too. I tried uploading a tarball via the Node-RED UI and followed the Request Body in the Dev Tools and I am guessing the only way is to capture the packets on the wire.

Comment: Is the server hosting the API not logging what it is receiving from the API call?  I know with the software we use at work the API call is logged on the receiving end so that we can troubleshoot.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-http-logger but Node Red does have a log setting.  I would suggest you set it to trace to see if it logs the API call.  I know that is how our software works.

Comment: That node will not help as admin API routes are independent of node routes

Comment: @hardillb do you know where the uploaded tarball via the API lands up in the filesystem for node-RED? I would like to check the base64 encoding logic because I doubt that the `uri` module does something to the tarball before uploading

Comment: `userDir/nodes` but the file is unpacked into a transient temp dir first to validate it contains the right metadata information in the `package.json` first, so if it fails to unpack there you will not see it because it will be deleted straight after the error is shown